# Nav Bar is not rendering properly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navbar

I'm relatively new with css, but was having an issue trying to accommodate all of the browsers, not surprisingly in this case, IE.

Here is my issue recreated on JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AgdGs/3/

In IE, the main problem is that the nav bar doesn't stay styled and will move below the logo.

I think this is a relatively easy fix, I just haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  It is likely that the nav element isn't supported for your version.  The nav element was introduced in HTML 5.

Comment: I want it to work on at least IE7. Well, that makes perfect sense, how do I solve that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Versions of IE lower than 9 do not natively [recognize the HTML5 semantic elements](http://caniuse.com/html5semantic) such as `<header>` and `<nav>`.

You need this in your `<head>`: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You will also need to set the HTML5 elements to `display: block`:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Comprehensive information here: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: Yup. Alternatively, drop back to the old-school way and [use a `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/J4xb7/2/), but it's not as nice, exciting and shiny as using `nav`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks everyone for all the help, it looks great! I definitely have to read up on HTML5 and what is new in it before I start using it.

Answer (score 1):

`<nav>` is `HTML5 element`, and only supported in latest browsers not older browsers, below IE 9

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in IE developer tools (I've tested this in IE8, you didn't mention what version you tested it in), the `UL` is moved outside the `nav` element.